# Special character 'Â' inserted before copyright symbol

Tags: firefox, character-encoding, stylesheet

Our source code contains a copyright at the top of every CSS file...

/* Copyright © ... */

Every time CSS files are loaded by the Firefox Style Editor, a special character is inserted before the copyright symbol...

/* Copyright Â© ... */

It adds an additional special character each time the file is loaded.  I do not believe this is limited to Firefox, but that's what I use at the moment for CSS dynamic styling.  It's annoying to have to delete this char every time and occasionally it gets into commits and pushed.

Question: How can the special character insertion be prevented?

Comment: Inserting an explicit @charset "UTF-8";  at the top of each .css file has no effect.

Comment: Found an easy way to reproduce this.  Load about:blank, right-click -> inspect element, choose style editor, and load any local .css file from disk with a copyright char.

Answer (score 11):

My advice is to open the files in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and check the detected encoding, as displayed under the *Encoding* menu. I expect that it will read:

> Encode in UTF-8

If so, apply *Convert to UTF-8-BOM*. It will prepend 3 *magic* bytes to your text file, making the UTF-8 encoding explicit. Save the files and see if it works.

**Explanation**

The reason for this Â to appear, is that some tool is not detecting the encoding correctly and assumes it is ANSI (a.k.a. [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)) or [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). Those one-bytes encodings and UTF-8 are very much alike for normal English texts and code files. The standard ASCII set is encoded in exactly the same way. Only special characters, like in your case, the copyright symbol, are encoded differently, using two, three of four bytes, rather than one.

Now, the *copyright symbol* has bytes [`0xC2 0xA9` or `11000010 10101001` in UTF-8 encoding](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9/index.htm), and byte [`0xA9` in ANSI encoding](http://www.table-ascii.com/).

The *latin capital letter A with circumflex* has byte `0xC2` or `11000010` in ANSI encoding.

When `11000010 10101001` is encountered and interpreted as UTF-8, the first three bits, of the first byte, `110`, in combination with the first two bits of the second byte , `10`,  indicate [the start of a two-byte UTF-8 character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). So this is the correct UTF-8 encoding of the copyright symbol.

If, however, `11000010 10101001` is encountered and interpreted as ANSI, two separate characters are seen, Â and ©.

I think it is no coincidence that the second byte of the UTF-8 encoding of © is the same as the one-byte ANSI encoding. It looks like [the Latin-1 supplement](http://graphemica.com/blocks/latin-1-supplement) is inserted in UTF-8 at exactly the [same order as it has in ANSI](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ansi.asp) and with the same offset, leaving the second bytes equal. E.g. a UTF-8 encoded

> µ

would show up as

> Âµ

if wrongly interpreted as ANSI.

Maybe, this was done to preserve some information about the original characters, if an encoding error were made.

Comment: Coming back to this... Manually inserting the BOM characters did not work.  Opening the file afterward ... ï»¿
/* Copyright Â© ... */.    I also noticed the same using Chrome Dev Tools.  However, opening .js files did not have this problem.  It's only with .css files.

Comment: @jmelvin, the additional characters in your output are the ANSI representation of the [UTF-8 byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8). So, even now you added an explicit BOM, the editor is still persistently interpreting it as ANSI. This is not what I see in the Firefox style editor. Maybe, you can solve the issue by converting it to ANSI, using something like Notepad++, or maybe replace the © by (c). If you have the css online, you could supply the url and I wil have a close look.

Comment: I've tried setting charset to UTF-8 in index.html,  the link tag that loads the main CSS file (which includes other CSS files), and also tried to insert a BOM in the main CSS file.  All to no avail.  Firefox style editor on Mac still insists interpreting it as ANSI.  You can check out the app staged at https://sizzlescene.com/sizzlesceneclient/dist/index.html and examine any CSS file.  Thanks for taking a peek. BTW running FF on Mac.

Comment: @jmelvin, I looked at the link just now, but currently there is only a minified version of main.css with no copyright comments and no imports of other css files.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using copyright symbol itself, try to use its numerical number:

```
&#169;
```

Answer (score 5):

Check if you have set a correct charset-meta-tag in your html head

```
<meta charSet="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: We do have the following set in the html head...      <meta charset='UTF-8'>

Comment: You can reproduce this locally very easily.  Use Firefox to load about:blank, right-click -> inspect element, choose style editor, and load any local .css file from disk with a copyright char.

Comment: I did this as well have use `&#169;` and it worked (both changes were required).