# Why does Â come left of copyright symbol?

Tags: html, css

Why does the special symbol "Â" come left of the copyright symbol?
I tried meta and it didn't work. I used Meta tag and still.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please include your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Special character 'Â' inserted before copyright symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966981/special-character-%c3%82-inserted-before-copyright-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

### Make sure you use the same character encoding throughout your project

Nowadays, that's usually [utf-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) because it's reasonably compact and supports global characters as well as emoji.

This happens specifically because [the © symbol is two bytes in utf-8](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A9/): 0xC2 0xA9. If these two bytes are saved to a file/ database etc, and then read using the wrong character encoding, it comes out as something else. Specifically 0xC2 in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) an extension of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is the character you're seeing - Â. Single byte encodings are very basic by today's standards as they only have a very small amount of characters.

As it seems like you're saving your text to a .html file and a browser is displaying it with the wrong encoding, add a doctype at the top of your file. The HTML5 doctype tells the browser to use utf-8 by default (if it didn't already), and the meta tag covers old browsers too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
    </head>
    <body>
    ©
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Close, and nicely explained, but Â is not ASCII which is a seven bit code so doesn't cover C2. The C2 is almost certainly being treated as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

Comment: @Alohci great point! I happened to look at [this random ascii table website](https://www.ascii-code.com/) and hadn't noticed it was in the extended range, just vaguely recalled that some European characters were added somewhere; updated.